# SAP BW: Error deleting request

Tags: request, sap-bw

In SAP BW I can delete requests. However when I try to delete a request I see a red status.

Mouseover shows "Fehler beim zurückrollen des requests DTP....; nur Rollback erlaubt"

When I click on the status icon I get the message "Der Request ist schon (teil-)aktiviert; Keine QM-Aktion mehr möglich"

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Seems similar to this: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3438197

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate says:

`"Failed to roll back the request DTP ...., only rollback allowed"`

and

`When I click on the status icon I get the message "The request is already (partial) activated, No QM action possible"`

("Only" might be better translated as "no"?)

Comment: Yes that's how you can translate the message - but this is not the answer to the question

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues Do you want me to remove it?  It does at least answer the first part of the question.  Not worth an upvote though.